# "be kept waiting" vs "be made to wait"

Tags: vocabulary

> - We were kept waiting for two hours.
> - We were made to wait for two hours.

Are both equally correct and common?

Comment: Both are equally annoying (but, alas, all too common).

Comment: Both seem correct (grammatically), I think the first is more common. Have you checked with Google Ngrams?

Comment: The passive voice is a little weird, especially in *made to wait*.  *He/she/they kept us waiting* is the most common way to express this.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable ways to phrase this unacceptable situation. However, according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kept%20waiting%2Cmade%20to%20wait&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckept%20waiting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmade%20to%20wait%3B%2Cc0) *kept waiting* is far more common (about 6x in 2000, around 10x 100 years ago).

Comment: But it should be noted that, because "made to wait" is rarer, it better expresses annoyance.  "Kept waiting" makes it sound a bit more like the wait was "normal" and expected.

Comment: To me, _made to wait_ just sounds more highbrow or snooty.

Comment: Perhaps [these Google Ngrams](_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20kept%20waiting%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20made%20to%20wait%20for%3B%2Cc0) give a more accurate picture by eliminating more noise. Here, instances for  'were kept waiting for' : 'were made to wait for' are just 3:1 in 2000.

Comment: Good point. _kept waiting_ could be part of other phrases, like _I kept waiting and waiting_.

Answer (score 1):

Americans use the passive voice if they want to emphasize the object rather than the agent.

In American English, "kept waiting" is more common and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.  Both are common in British English.  Neither is common in US English.  A US speaker would say "He kept us waiting" or "He made us wait."

Comment: Did someone tell you Americans don't use passive voice? Maybe we use it less than in the U.K., but not by much. See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+kept+waiting%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+were+kept+waiting%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+were+made+to+wait%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+were+made+to+wait%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20kept%20waiting%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20kept%20waiting%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20made%20to%20wait%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20made%20to%20wait%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)